# We have no [knowledge] of this tag

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, burninate-request

The Meta Stack Exchange tag [knowledge](/questions/tagged/knowledge) has ten questions about many different topics. It does not have a tag wiki or excerpt. Since about *everything* we do here is asking for or sharing knowledge, I think this tag is completely superfluous and should be burninated. Thoughts?

Comment: I have removed all the incorrect usages of that tag (and added / changed tags a couple of times), leaving [only **5** uses](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/knowledge); hopefully focused correctly. --- The tag isn't about "Knowledge" in general, but the application of it. If you still decide to burniate then half the work is done; but I think that ***now*** it deserves to stay - and have a wiki so it's used correctly in future. --- The first user of a tag should always at least write the excerpt.

Comment: @Rob Its worth making a case for it then. Why does it deserve to stay? What should its scope be? It feels like a meta tag to me but I can be wrong ;D

Comment: @JourneymanGeek, The [oldest link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/21810/282094) talks about how knowledge should be presented ('is the Q&A format *best*', but we also have kludged our format to have FAQs, even [tag:Announcement] *questions* (where *technically* there is no answer)). The [second oldest question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/41606/282094) uses the tag to question if we are disseminating knowledge in a manner that people will be receptive to (are we kind, helpful, or rude and condescending).

Comment: @JourneymanGeek ...,  The [most recent usage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76901/282094) seems to suggest that a means to *bundle* a group of tags would be a better way to present knowledge for a specific project, perhaps with a limited audience; maybe even a Team Feature Request. --- With its three uses it's a rare tag, but that doesn't necessarily mean that it should go; if it's used correctly. The above should be approximately its scope. - It's true that a tag such as "words" would be quite ambiguous as all posts contain words, but a tag such as "colloquialisms" may be much better used.

Comment: @Rob I currently see only one question in the rag that isn't closed, the oldest one. That question questions the principles on which SO was founded, the way we share knowledge (the Q&A format). Knowledge is only tangentially correlated tiothat question IMHO, as it is **not about** knowledge, but about the principles of SO.

Comment: @Luuklag, we are continuing the conversation in The Tavern; I think there's a couple of comments about your above comment's question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To the best of my [knowledge](/questions/tagged/knowledge) there is only one thing we can do: **Let's unleash the burnination dragon!**

EDIT:

### This tag has been: [image]

Comment: TROGDOR! 

Comment: Do we have [knowledge] of Trogdor?

Comment: (answer accepted awaiting edit confirming burnination completion)

Comment: I put in the dragon this morning @Glorfindel